Azure Log Analytics only allow access to one specific table
I'm trying to allow team members to view one specific table in a Log Analytics Workspace.
I added the Table IAM role Reader for that specific user, but they couldn't access the workspace that way. Hence I added Reader to the workspace IAM, but that allows access to all tables.
Is there a way to allow someone access to Log Analytics but only query one table?

Have you tried any approach to do the same? @nindustries

What do you mean @Jahnavi?

I mean to ask that other than adding and removing the roles, have you checked any other relevant approaches through code? @nindustries

I haven't tried azure cli yet, and was hoping we could use the UI for this.

Ok will check on it. @nindustries


Azure Log Analytics only allow access to one specific table:

To allow access to a specific table in log analytics workspaces, you can follow below steps as detailed.
Refer Set table-level read access MS Doc.

Go to your Log analytics workspace >> Access Control (IAM) >> Roles as shown in the below image.



It redirects you to below page to create a custom role. Add below under actions[] block by clicking on edit Json option.

"Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/read",
"Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/query/read"


Once it's done, click on save changes and custom role will be created.

After all the above procedure, the new custom role will be visible now under Access control (IAM) >> roles.
Now go to Access control (AIM) >> Add >> Add role assignment for the specific user or service principal according to your requirement.
